# Is possible to declare string type with restricted length that doesn't start from 0/1?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In Delphi it is possible to declare subranges for integer values. For example:

```
type
  myInt = 2..150
```

Which restricts values of myInt type to values from 2 to 150. But what if I want to restrict the length of a string?

If I write:

```
type 
  myString = string [150]
```

I declare mystring to be 150 bytes long and restrict the length to be from 0, 1, 2, etc. up to 150. But how do I restrict the length to between 2 and 150, for example? 
Of course, I can check the length of a string and raise an exception, but does Delphi include some syntax specific to this situation, similar in style to subranges?

This obviously does not work, but I would like something like:

```
type
  myString = string[2..150]
```

If it is not possible, then I can just check length, raise exception, etc.

---

trying this code:

```
var
 str1, str2, str3: TRestrictedString;
begin
  str1.Create(2, 5, 'pp');
  str2.Create(2, 5, 'aaaa');
  str3.Create(2, 10, str1 + str2);
  writeln (str3.getstring)
end
```

or:

```
var
 str1, str2, str3: TRestrictedString;
begin
  str1.Create(2, 5, 'pp');
  str2.Create(2, 5, 'aaaa');
  str3.Create(2, 10);
  str3.SetString(str1 + str2);
  writeln (str3.getstring)
end
```

or:

```
var
 str1, str2, str3: TRestrictedString;
begin
  str1.Create(2, 5, 'pp');
  str2.Create(2, 5, 'aaaa');
  str3.Create(2, 10);
  str3 := str1 + str2;
  writeln(str3.GetString);
end
```

All of these raise an exception. Is possible to solve this? For multiple operations on a string is it necessary to split the function into more parts? 
In the constructor, is it better to add a check that `minlength < maxlength`? If I set `minlength > maxlength` it raises an exception.

Comment: Your can't do this with the built in string types.

As a wild thought experiment you could implement this with a record type and  operator overloading. It would make more sense to wrap this data in a property and control the setting of that property.

Comment: No, this isn't possible with a `String` type. You can't set a minimum length for a string, although using `ShortString` you can set a max.

Comment: @Ken: But then you'll loose everything Unicode...

Comment: @Andreas, of course. :) That's why my answer was "No". The OP didn't mention Unicode in his question; the question was about a minimum and maximum length for a string type.

Comment: @Marcello - just to pick up on a point - the first character of a delphi string is *MyString[1]*

Comment: `packed array [2..150] of Char` is the best you can do.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, to be close to `string` as much as possible

Comment: @Downvoter: packed has absolutely no effect on arrays, in Delphi.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis, yes **in Delphi as particular implementation** :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would do

```
type
  TRestrictedString = record
  strict private type
    TBounds = record
      MinLength,
      MaxLength: integer;
    end;
  strict private
    FStr: string;
  public
    Bounds: TBounds;
    procedure SetString(const AString: string);
    function GetString: string;
    constructor Create(AMinLength, AMaxLength: integer); overload;
    constructor Create(AMinLength, AMaxLength: integer; const AString: string); overload;
    constructor Create(const AString: string); overload;
    class operator Implicit(S: string): TRestrictedString;
    class operator Implicit(S: TRestrictedString): string;
    class operator Equal(const A, B: TRestrictedString): boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const A, B: TRestrictedString): boolean;
    class operator Add(const A, B: TRestrictedString): TRestrictedString;
  end;

{ TRestrictedString }


constructor TRestrictedString.Create(AMinLength, AMaxLength: integer);
begin
  Bounds.MinLength := AMinLength;
  Bounds.MaxLength := AMaxLength;
  FStr := '';
end;

constructor TRestrictedString.Create(AMinLength, AMaxLength: integer;
  const AString: string);
begin
  Bounds.MinLength := AMinLength;
  Bounds.MaxLength := AMaxLength;
  SetString(AString);
end;

class operator TRestrictedString.Add(const A,
  B: TRestrictedString): TRestrictedString;
begin
  result.Bounds := A.Bounds;
  result.SetString(A.GetString + B.GetString);
end;

constructor TRestrictedString.Create(const AString: string);
begin
  Bounds.MinLength := 0;
  Bounds.MaxLength := MaxInt;
  FStr := AString;
end;

class operator TRestrictedString.Equal(const A, B: TRestrictedString): boolean;
begin
  result := A.GetString = B.GetString;
end;

function TRestrictedString.GetString: string;
begin
  result := FStr;
end;

class operator TRestrictedString.Implicit(S: TRestrictedString): string;
begin
  result := S.GetString;
end;

class operator TRestrictedString.NotEqual(const A,
  B: TRestrictedString): boolean;
begin
  result := A.GetString <> B.GetString;
end;

class operator TRestrictedString.Implicit(S: string): TRestrictedString;
begin
  result.Create(S);
end;

procedure TRestrictedString.SetString(const AString: string);
begin
  with Bounds do
    if (length(AString) < MinLength) or (length(AString) > MaxLength) then
      raise Exception.Create('Invalid length of string.');
  FStr := AString;
end;
```

Now you can do very natural things, like

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  str: TRestrictedString;
begin
  str.Create(5, 10);         // Create a string w/ length 5 to 10 chrs
  str.SetString('Testing!'); // Assign a compatible string
  ShowMessage(str);          // Display the string
end;
```

You can also do just

```
str.Create(5, 10, 'Testing!');
ShowMessage(str);
```

You can add string the usual way:

```
var
  s1, s2, s3: TRestrictedString;
begin
  s1.Create(2, 10, 'Hi ');
  s2.Create(2, 10, 'there!');
  s3 := s1 + s2;
  ShowMessage(s3);
end;
```

or even

```
var
  s1, s3: TRestrictedString;
begin
  s1.Create(2, 10, 'Hi ');
  s3 := s1 + 'there!';
  ShowMessage(s3);
```

When you add two `TRestrictedString`s, or one `TRestrictedString` and a `string`, the result will have the same restriction as the first operand. You can try

```
var
  str: TRestrictedString;
begin
  str.Create(5, 10);
  str.SetString('Testing!');
  str := str + '!!';
  ShowMessage(str);
```

which will work, but not

```
var
  str: TRestrictedString;
begin
  str.Create(5, 10);
  str.SetString('Testing!');
  str := str + '!!!';
  ShowMessage(str);
```

Just beware that *assigning* a `string` to a `TRestrictedString` will also assign the 'bounds' of the string, that is, the `TRestrictedString` will have bounds set to `0` and `MaxInt`. Thus, no matter how a `s: TRestrictedString` is restricted, an assignment `s := 'some string'` will always work.

**Update**: Chris Rolliston used this answer as inspiration for a very interesting [article](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/bounded-strings-using-advanced-records/).

Comment: `FStr := ''` in constructor doesn't satisfy the min length constraint. Note: having suggested the idea (I'm sure you had it independently) I'm now going to try to find holes in your implementation!  ;-)  +1 also.

Comment: InRange would be good. Also, I don't know a written way to express the sucking through teeth sound when I saw the with.....  ;-)

Comment: @David: As for your first remark, what in the world do you suggest I'd do otherwise? Fill the string with "Lorem ipsum dolor..."?

Comment: @David: Of course I thought about it, but I think it is a bit awkward to have to include `uses Math` just to be able to use `InRange`...

Comment: Force the constructor to receive a string by removing the no value constructor. Or have the no value constructor but get it to call SetString. But then record constructors aren't quite what you need here since you can instantiate one of these records without calling a constructor. So you are in a bind.

Comment: +1 for the effort. But I think it actually demonstrates that the practical answer is "Yes, but it's not worth the trouble."

Comment: +1 for this great example of the power of Delphi records and overloading to create really flexible value types.

Comment: @Jeroen It also casts a bright light on their weaknesses, namely the inability to require a constructor. In this case the code could be reworked to object unless it had been properly initialized but that results in annoying boilerplate.

Comment: @Hugh: "With" is usually a reason for me to -1, but not this time. <g>

Comment: @ChrisThornton: If it is worth the trouble depends on how great the need for such a type is. It would be a little overdone to design such a type for a one-off situation, but if there are more places it is required, why not something like this? Or if it is an existing type in a large library, it makes sense to use it.