# Defining a string type to be a certain format

Tags: string, delphi, casting, delphi-7

I was wondering if there's a way to define a type of string or similar in delphi 7 which is intended to be in a particular format, or matching certain specifications? For example, I'd like to define a `TSizeString` type which accepts values such as `4x6` or `9x12` or maybe even `2.5x10.75`. It should require the `x` as the only deliminator between two numbers. So there should never be anything like `x9` or `65` or `2-4` or `4-6x6-2` and not even `4 x 6`.

Just `INTEGER + 'x' + INTEGER` or `SINGLE + 'x' + SINGLE`.

Similar I guess to how like a TFilename works, standard filenames may look like `C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt` or `\\Storage\SomeDir\SomeFile.doc`

Comment: There is nothing magic about `TFilename`. It is simply defined as `type TFileName = type string`. You can assign a mathematical formula, or a Shakespeare novel, to a variable of type `TFileName`.

Comment: Anyhow, this can be achieved using advanced records and operator overloading. I have written samples [about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588377/is-possible-declare-string-type-with-specific-lenght-that-not-start-from-0-1) [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021205/can-i-define-mytype-that-can-contain-only-these-values). I don't remember if Delphi 7 supports advanced records/operator overloading, though.

Comment: As I mention in a comment below, can I use a class with an `AsString` property the default of the class? I mean, if I publish a string property of the class as `Default` of the class, can I read/write that class as if it were a string?

Comment: Or does that only apply to using an indexed property?

Comment: Default properties have to be indexed.

Comment: Can someone please explain the -3 votes? Is there something not legitimate about this question or how I'm asking it? Or do I just have some haters? :P

Comment: I'm going to ask another new question more specifically what I need help with, because this question is too broad and I'm sure I've already been using the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special types, like TFileName and TCaption are nothing special, like Andreas mentioned, but they can be used to register a specific property editor in the IDE. This will help entering such values through the object inspector.

To really enforce such a value, if your string is a property of an object, you can write a setter for it.

Otherwise, I should make a TSize class that has properties for the two integers, and an AsString property that combines its properties to a string.

```
type
  TSize = class
  private
    FLeftInt, FRightInt: Integer;
    function GetString: string;
    procedure SetString(Value: string);
  public
    property LeftInt: Integer read FLeftInt write FLeftInt;
    property RightInt: Integer read FRightInt write FRightInt;
    property AsString: string read GetString write SetString;
  end;

function TSize.GetString: string;
begin
  Result := Format('%dx%d', [FLeftInt, FRightInt]);
end;

function TSize.SetString(Value: string);
begin
  // Validate and parse Value. Set LeftInt and RightInt.
end;
```

Comment: That's almost exactly to what I already have, TDimensions but I was wondering if there was a much lighter weight version, since I may be handling thousands of these at a time.

Comment: Actually just an idea, I can rather store the string instead of the 2 integers, and parse it out as needed to be read. This would allow users to enter and maintain different formats, so long as they follow some basic rules. At the same time, I could probably publish the AsString property as the class' default... right?

Comment: Well I meant lighter weight as in using a record rather than a class, not having to create/destroy this class would be great, but not gonna happen :D

Comment: Well, you could use `object` since you are stuck on D7. Would be slick in modern Delphi with op. overloads and records. Are you using FastMM? Did you profile the code yet?

Comment: You seem very determined to get me to upgrade :P But I'm also stuck using the license of whatever my workplace is providing me, and I don't have one for XE2 yet :(

Comment: No, just point out the info. I stayed on D6 for a very long time, only upgraded 18 months ago. But you should be using FastMM for your heap allocation and object can give you stack allocated OOP in D7.

Comment: An alternative would be to implement an object that is a wrapper around a TList. You can call it TSizeList and store records (or maybe just two Words if those are large enough). You can implement `GetAsString(Index)`, `SetAsString(Index, Value)`, `AddAsString(Value)`, `Add(LeftInt, RightInt)` and all kinds of other methods you need. But like David said, this is already pretty lightweight. Creating the objects themselves isn't much work at all.

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of Delphi, advanced records and operator overloading are very handy in this case:

```
type
  TSizeString = record
    x, y: single;
  public
    class operator Implicit(const S: string): TSizeString;
    class operator Implicit(const S: TSizeString): string;
  end;

implementation

class operator TSizeString.Implicit(const S: string): TSizeString;
var
  DelimPos: integer;
begin
  DelimPos := Pos('x', S);
  if (DelimPos = 0) or (not TryStrToFloat(Copy(S, 1, DelimPos-1), result.X)) or
    (not TryStrToFloat(Copy(S, DelimPos + 1), result.y)) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid format of size string "%s".', [S]);
end;

class operator TSizeString.Implicit(const S: TSizeString): string;
begin
  result := FloatToStr(S.x) + 'x' + FloatToStr(S.y);
end;
```

Now you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: TSizeString;
begin
  S := '20x30';             // works
  ShowMessage(S);
  S := 'Hello World!';      // exception raised
  ShowMessage(S);
end;
```

In older versions of Delphi, you simply have to write a class, or create a basic record to hold your size (and then, of course, you can create functions that convert between such records and formatted strings).

Comment: Nice demo, but no solution for the OP, since it won't work on Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just to use a function, and always use it when defining your strings...

```
function MyString(numA, numB: single) : string;
begin
    Result := FloatToStr(numA) + 'x' + FloatToStr(numB)
end;
```

If you want to get fancier, you can do it as a class which allows a direct string assignment as a property, but which parses the string for compliance.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I'd like to explicitly define a type of some sort, not just tweak how a property works.